# Deletion Confirmation in Web-based application

Tags: java, jsp, confirmation

Good day!

How is the confirmation for deletion usually done in Web-based applications? I often use JOptionPane in doing the confirmation messages in my Java desktop applications so I am also thinking of doing the same in my web-application. Is there something like JOptionPane in J2EE?

So my plan of confirmation message is something like [THIS](http://trentrichardson.com/Impromptu/demos/demo1.php) because I find it cool. Is it possible to code this using Java (JSP/Servlets)? Where can i find sample codes (or what term should i search so i'll learn it)?

Also, why haven't I encountered many pop-ups when visiting different websites? Are pop-up messages not a good practice in web-apps? If it's not a good practice, how can i do it to conform to the standards?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to code this using Java (JSP/Servlets)?

Both mentioned technologies are server-side, while client interaction such as popups are client-side. So yes, using a client-side popup in e.g., `javascript` will work fine with jsp.

> Are pop-up messages not a good practice in web-apps?

Popups are usually considered *evil* and annoying. They do make sense however when used to confirm e.g., a *delete* operation. Perhaps the [jQuery UI dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation) could be useful for you.

Answer (score 1):

One option that you may consider is using the [Google Web Toolkit (GWT)](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/), which allows you to program in java, and gives you nice widgets for doing things like popup etc. (note: those widget ultimately use javascript, but you don't have to care about it).

Answer (score 1):

the simplest way the achieve this principle is using the [javascript confirm function](http://www.htmlite.com/JS006.php).

Does what it needs to do but net very cool of course.
The easiest way to achieve something cool is using a js framework like jquery: like [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/#modal-confirmation).

Jquery and similar frameworks will create a semi-transparent layer on your window with a (dialog) div inside it. The layer itself blocks any actions that are behind it so this can be seen as a 'modal dialog'.

regards,
Stijn

Answer (score 1):

That's being done in the browser with JavaScript, specifically techniques called AJAX. You can choose from a number of different AJAX frameworks. I would recommned [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/). You could also use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) or [Dojo](http://www.dojotoolkit.org/), or try the Wikipedia [List of AJAX frameworks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Ajax_frameworks).